# Jmeter: how to initialise header manager element globally

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to use the same set of headers in multiple jmx files. So I wanted to initialise it once and have to use it across my jmx files.
Can anyone help me in meeting my requirement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not possible.
To be able to apply a Header Manager to all plan, it should have the largest scope but using Include or Module controller means reduced scope.

Thanks to scope stil, you can set your Header Manager as child of  test plan and it will apply to whole requests.

You could use properties and __P function to make those configurable in user.properties

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

1. Create a CSV file called `headers.csv` to hold your headers like:

   ```
   header-1-name,header-1-value
   header-2-name,header-2-value
   ```

   and store it in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Add empty [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to the top level of your Test Plan
3. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) to your Test Plan
4. Add [JSR223 Sample](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)r to the setUp Thread Group
5. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass

   SampleResult.setIgnore()

   def engine = ctx.getEngine()
   def testPlanTree = org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.readDeclaredField(engine, "test", true)

   def headerManagerSearch = new SearchByClass<>(HeaderManager.class)
   testPlanTree.traverse(headerManagerSearch)
   def headerManagers = headerManagerSearch.getSearchResults()
   headerManagers.any { headerManager ->
       new File('headers.csv').readLines().each { line ->
           def values = line.split(',')
           headerManager.add(new Header(values[0], values[1]))
       }
   }
   ```

   [image]

   6. If you want you can "externalize" points 3 and 4 via [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)